# Запрос SPARQL к RDF

Tags: sql

Есть файл в формате RDF, описывающий онтологию предметной области. И есть запрос SPARQL. Как состыковать как одно с другим и получить результат этого запроса к этому rdf?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо оболочку, в которой можно отправить этот запрос - это либо какая-то графовая база данных.
Либо можете использовать бесплатное [ПО Protege](https://protege.stanford.edu/)
Там во вкладке windows -> tabs можно включить вкладку со SPARQL и отправлять запросы в предложенном интерфейсе. Также такую возможность поддерживает Ontotext